# gedit 3 regex search replace plugin port

Tags: gtk, gedit, plugins, regex

So i have been trying to install this plugin:

http://halfhourhacks.blogspot.com/2008/03/gedit-regular-expression-plugin.html

in gedit 3.2.1 but there seem to be some issues. I have modified the .plugin file and now it shows up in the list of plugins. But when i try to select the plugin from the list, gedit closes. So i noticed that the plugin import modules from GTK+2 so i tried changing them to the GTK+3 equivalents. Also a lot of the built in plugins code look slightly different than this plugin. After making changes to init.py, when i click on the plugin from the list of plugins that is in the list, a error icon shows up next to the plugin name and it gets greyed out. Has anyone been able to port this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there have been updates to this plugin to support the GTK+3 toolkit.

**Update**

Here is another plugin I found recently that works well and seems more stable :

https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/gedit-re-search/wiki/Home

Answer (score 1):

The plugin system of gedit changed between version 2 and 3.

You will not be able to install the old version of the plugin, and as long as you don't show your modifications, error messages and all, you will not be able to get a good answer.

If you want to change the plugin yourself, you can look at the [plugin-writing-guide for gedit3](http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html).